# I cant input text into my form

Tags: php, html, forms, input

Here is my code, when i try and select the text field the page will not let me input text.

```
    <form method=post action=/form-energy.php enctype='multipart/form-data'>
       <label for=name>Name:</label> <input name=name id=name type=text><br>
       <label for=tel>Tel:</label> <input name=tel id=tel type=tel><br>
       <label for=email>Email:</label> <input name=email id=email type=text><br>
       <label for=architect>Architect details:</label> <textarea name=architect id=architect rows=10></textarea><br>
       <p class=drawings>If you have any drawings to submit, please do so below (max file size 10mb):</p>
       <label for=drawings>Drawings:</label> <input type=file name=drawings id=drawings><br><br>
       <input type=submit value="Get in touch">
  </form>
```

Comment: a perfect example of too localized question.

Comment: I just built [a page with your code](http://jsbin.com/osuniy/1/edit) and cannot reproduce the problem. (So voting to close as it doesn't contain a example of the problem).

Comment: Likewise with Quentin, I can input text just fine. Can you explain the problem any further?

Comment: Agreed with _Quentin_ and _MLeFevre_. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/Jxv6L/) is a fiddle with a copy and paste of your code. Works just fine in Chrome...

Comment: sorry if i wasted anyones time, i just cant get it to work online. here is the page containing the form so you can see what i mean. http://sdconsultancy.co.uk/building-control.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your CSS. You've put `z-index` of your `div#content` to -1, so it's under the body and nothing can be clicked in it. You can, however, use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to your form elements.